# jQuery Remote validation check ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I've a form that checks whether email exists or not, while signing up. My server responds with a status `true/false`.

```
{'status': true/false}
```

If email exists, then it returns `false`, meaning the new user cannot signup with that email. If it returns `true`, then the user is free to take the mail.

How do I display an error depending on the status key field.??

Here is my code:-

```
rules: {
    user_email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: "/check_email_exist/",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                email: function() {
                    return $( "#signup_form :input[name='user_email']" ).val();
                }
            },
            success: function(response) {
                    if (response['status'] == true){
                        alert(111)  // does alert
                        messages:{  // but does not prints the message.
                            user_email: {
                                remote: jQuery.validator.format("Email {0} does not exists. Kindly check the mail.")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

PS:- I know I can send either `true/false` directly from the server, ie just a boolean response, not a dictionary. But the thing is response can be anything, not specifically to `true/false` as in this case.

I've tried adding `addMethod` but `check_mail` is always false.

```
rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            check_email: true
        }
    },
$.validator.addMethod("check_email", function (value, element) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'/check_email_exist/',
        data: {'email' : value},
        success:function(result)
        {   
            if(result == 'false'){
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    })
},jQuery.validator.format("Email does not exists. Kindly check the mail."));
```

Comment: Maybe try to use different HTML response codes to differentiate *true* or *false*. But what do you mean that response can be anything? So what kind of responses determine *true* and what kind of responses determine *false*?

Comment: Can be anything. Integers as well. For eg:- If response is `1`, then show error, else if response is `2` then success.

Comment: I think it is impossible to determine if something is true or false if you do not assume some restrictions on it. You have to know what types and values the status field can have.